# HTML img rover effect changes size of image

Tags: html, rollover

I have the following code to create a rollover effect in HTML:

```
<img src="images/facebook.png"
onmouseover='this.src="images/facebookActive.png"' 
onmouseout='this.src="image/facebook.png"' height="32px" width="32px"/>
```

It starts out fine, however upon hovering over it, it goes back to its original size (500x500). I have attempted to add height="32px" width="32px" to each attribute, however it doesn't seem to help. Also, by decreasing the size of the image using GIMP, quality is lost and it becomes more pixelated. Any help on this situation?

Comment: Does using CSS (`style='width:32px;height:32px;'`) work?

Comment: If you only want to show this picture with 32x32px dimensions you should shrink it to this size before to save bandwidth. Of course quality is lost if you decrease the size to a rather small icon as information is lost. However, the browser is doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your scenario but I'm unable to do that. So can you edit this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mkf5C/) to reproduce your issue. try to use your images.

```
<img src="http://netdna.copyblogger.com/images/flogo.jpg" onmouseover='this.src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ6y qrcyQQxC6hISHmE37Yk2IUsOQtACy8NvcQgxMA0Uk3er5y"' onmouseout='this.src="http://netdna.copyblogger.com/images/flogo.jpg"' height="32px" width="32px" />
```

It seems to be working fine. Also Try re sizing the image using [PNGGauntlet](http://pnggauntlet.com/)

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried setting the `this.width` and `this.height` in `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`?

Comment: **After** setting the new `src`?